# Technical terms for an oven that would resist to cleaning products wipping out painted symbols?

Tags: equipment, oven

Hi not sure if anyone could help with this but I aim to buy an oven that would keep its settings symbols for a decent amount of time. Would be great if ovens had a technical term(s) that would indicate the ability of the oven to withstand cleaning products from removing painted symbols?

I have spent already 30 minutes looking all over the internet and could not figure out how I could possibly find out the answer to this. Looking to buy online does not give you much of an indication whether the symbols are engraved, painted or behind a glass window?

Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, it is not an issue, I've been clean my oven, inside and out for 15 years and there are no problem with removing painted decals or not.

Unless you are using really harsh cleaning product or too much abrasive, you should not have an issue.

Comment: Agreed it may not be easy to wipe out the settings and yet people always manage to do it. I would want to eliminate the possibility of this happening as much as possible.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It only states that you have never had this issue.